# Run tests on a project under the same solution running on localhost Selenium

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selenium

How do I run Selenium tests on the main project if the main and the test project are in the same solution and running on localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy the mvc website into IIS (local/remote) and use the URL in selenium to invoke your project.  e.g. driver.get("http://localhost/website/default.aspx")